# Can't get filter to work with multiple conditions

Tags: filter, ssas, ssms, mdx

I'm trying to make a MDX query for use with SSRS later on. To start with the basic query that works:

```
Select NON EMPTY {
[Measures].[Score %]
,[Measures].[Month Key]
} on Columns,
NON EMPTY {
([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301])
* FILTER([Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
        ([Measures].[Score %], [Date].[YMD].&[201301]) <> null
    AND ([Measures].[Score %], [Date].[YMD].&[201301]) <> 0 ) 
} on Rows

from [Cube]
```

But this is only for one month. in SSRS i want to be able to select multiple months, so i altered my query to this:

```
Select NON EMPTY {
 [Measures].[Score %]
,[Measures].[Month Key]
} on Columns,
NON EMPTY {
([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307])
* FILTER([Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
        ([Measures].[Score %], ([Date].[YMD].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].&[201307]))<> null
    AND ([Measures].[Score %], ([Date].[YMD].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].&[201307])) <> 0 )
} on Rows

from [Cube]
```

But here i get an error: The <> function expects a string or numeric expression for the 1 argument. A tuple set expression was used.

As far as i understand it is because i'm returning multiple months in my set where it expects one month. So i write the next query:

```
With
Set [QC relation]
as FILTER([Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
          ([Measures].[Score %], [Date].[YMD].currentmember) <> null
    AND   ([Measures].[Score %], [Date].[YMD].currentmember) <> 0 ) 

Select NON EMPTY {
 [Measures].[Score %]
,[Measures].[Month Key]
} on Columns,
NON EMPTY {
([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307]) 
* [QC relation]
} on Rows

from [Cube]
```

But here it seems my filter doesn't work properly. It is returning all the rows with a score in the data for each month so i have a lot of null values.

How do i get the proper results for each month without the null values? 
I'm working with SSMS/SSAS on SQLServer2008

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reworking your query I end up with this, let me know how it goes:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{
     [Measures].[Score %]
    ,[Measures].[Month Key]
} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
{
    ([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307])
    * 
    FILTER
    (
        [Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
        SUM({[Date].[YMD].CURRENTMEMBER}, [Measures].[Score %])<> null
        AND 
        SUM({[Date].[YMD].CURRENTMEMBER}, [Measures].[Score %])<> 0
    )
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Or an even simpler version might work:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{
     [Measures].[Score %]
    ,[Measures].[Month Key]
} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
{
    ([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307])
    * 
    FILTER
    (
        [Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members,
        [Measures].[Score %] <> null
        AND 
        [Measures].[Score %] <> 0
    )
} ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Edit: Third attempt, let's see if this does the trick:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
{
     [Measures].[Score %]
    ,[Measures].[Month Key]
} ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY 
{
    ([Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201301] : [Date].[YMD].[Month Name].&[201307])
    * 
    [Customer].[Customer Full Name].[Customer Full Name].members
} 
HAVING  [Measures].[Score %] <> null
AND [Measures].[Score %] <> 0
ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

Comment: Hi Meff, thanks for your reply. With your rework i get less records, but still a lot of null values. FYI: march, april and may are empty but i do get records for those months.

Comment: @Maestrodude edited as I realised the error - You're saying "Show me month by month, and show me anyone who has a value in the whole date range", you want to say "Show me month by month, and show me anyone who has a value for that month".

Comment: thanks again :-) but i still get to many results with null. I think because of the fact that you have to check for each month to aply the filter, otherwise you get all the customers who had a score in the total data.

Comment: @Maestrodude, could you try the third query I edited into my post, see if that does the trick. Without having your cube here I'm having a little trouble with the MDX :/

Comment: that does the trick. Now i'm getting the expected results. Thanks a lot!